# Qemu fails to create socket

Tags: sockets, qemu, dpdk, ubuntu-22.04

In my `ubuntu22.04.xml` configuration I have:

```
<qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-chardev'/>
    <qemu:arg value='socket,id=chr0,path=/tmp/sock0,server=on'/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

The socket will be created by Qemu, so just check permissions:

```
$ ls -la /tmp
total 84
drwxrwxrwt 21 root  root  4096 Aug  8 05:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root  root  4096 Apr 20 08:07 ..
...etc
$ ls -la /tmp/sock0 
ls: cannot access '/tmp/sock0': No such file or directory
```

However, I see this error:

```
$ virsh start ubuntu22.04 
error: Failed to start domain 'ubuntu22.04'
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2023-08-07T20:58:25.810334Z
                qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=chr0,path=/tmp/sock0,server=on:
                                    Failed to bind socket to /tmp/sock0: Permission denied
```

If I create the socket in another program before running, I get instead:

```
$ virsh start ubuntu22.04 
error: Failed to start domain 'ubuntu22.04'
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2023-08-07T20:57:56.240729Z
                qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=chr0,path=/tmp/sock0,server=on:
                                    Failed to unlink socket /tmp/sock0: Permission denied
```

What could be the reason for the permission error?

**UPDATE:** Looking at `dmesg`, I see a possible error:

```
[ 3369.733844] audit: type=1400 audit(1691444094.488:178): apparmor="DENIED"
    operation="mknod" class="file" profile="libvirt-ea182d75-dd38-41dd-b227-5b871b0a77bb"
    name="/tmp/sock0" pid=9163 comm="qemu-system-x86" 
    requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=64055 ouid=64055
```

What does this indicate?

I am trying to reproduce the [example here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-22.11/sample_app_ug/vhost.html) with DPDK v22.11.2.